# GCP Mysql instance is not taking VARCHAR limit more than 3072

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We are using GCP based mysql server for our application. For one of the column we need to increase the limit for varchar from default 255.

Please see below query and error :-

```
ALTER TABLE data_key MODIFY COLUMN key VARCHAR(8000);
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes
```

This is working as expected on local mysql DB but not on mysql of GCP. Do we have restriction on GCP for limits else how can limit be increased or change of data type is possible (last option).

Output of show create table data_key :

data_key table

```
CREATE TABLE data_key ( 
    id int(11) NOT NULL, 
    key varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE KEY US_mypr3ns15fjs031li0iwa6sdf4nk` (key ) 
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using locally and what version on the cloud

Comment: Both are latest and compatible

Comment: ?Latest? Is not very informative. According to a google page I just read then you are using MySQL 5.7 as they do not yet support MySQL8. You see how confusing the word **latest** could be in this situation

Comment: This limit is the maximum that MySQL supports, so it should also apply to your local database. Are you certain that you have an (unprefixed) index in your local db, e.g. can you add the table definition (the output of `show create table data_key`) to your question?

Comment: Please post that as an edit to your question. It is difficult to read code in a comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly Both are 5.7

Comment: Then I cannot find anywhere in the documentation that allows a key larger than 3072

Comment: Is this the code for the local table? It still uses `varchar(255)`, maybe the `alter` on your local db didn't work and you just missed the error message (the same you get on the google db). If this is not the local table: please add the description for the local table (after altering to `varchar(8000)`)

Comment: @Solarflare The description is from local DB table. I am trying various solutions thus deleting and adding schema frequently. I am assuring after ALTER query, the size is changed on local DB not on GCP.

Comment: So can you add this altered table? It should not work locally either, so if it does, there is some (maybe very subtle) difference from what you are describing here, but it is hard to guess what it might be and probably easy after seeing the new table structure (after altering).

Comment: Just as an example for subtle things: if the index is actually not unqiue and your sql mode is not strict, mysql will automatically prefix your index without giving you an error message. Some variation of this probably happened in your case, but you might think "unique" is not that relevant enough, while we could spot both (the automatic prefix and the non-uniqueness), and the answer is a matter of seconds instead of guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this error occured is InnoDB engine[1]. If you use MySQL Second Generation on Google Cloud, InnoDB is the only storage engine supported [2]. For MySQL First Generation instances, the InnoDB storage engine is recommended.

In InnoDB innodb_large_prefix is enabled by default, the index key prefix limit is 3072 bytes for InnoDB tables that use DYNAMIC or COMPRESSED row format. This was introduced in MySQL 5.5 to disable large index key prefixes for compatibility with earlier versions of InnoDB that do not support large index key prefixes. It was deprecated and removed in future releases [3].

In your case you can create a First Generation MySQL instance[4], but be aware that support for First Generation instances ends January 30, 2020 and set up another storage engine[5].

---

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/faq#innodb

[3] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html#innodb-maximums-minimums

[4] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance#create-1st-gen

[5] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html